# How to read UART port data via Ethernet Raspberry 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I am using a Raspbee device with raspberry pi 3. The rasbee is attached to the UART ports of the Pi 3 as shown in attached figure.

The communication between raspbee and pi3 is done through UART ports. I want to read the packets exchanged b/w pi 3 and raspbee via Ethernet. The packets will be decoded using the wireshark installed in the PC.

I cannot figure out how to read the UARTs port data via ethernet for raspberry pi 3.

[image]

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood the question I think you need [ser2net](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ser2net) installed and configured on the Pi. This will connect the USART to a TCP port and you can then use something like `telnet`, `netcat` or PuTTY to connect to and interact with the Raspbee.
Not sure why you want to use Wireshark though, are you saying you already have a process running on the Pi that's controlling the Raspbee and you want to spy on the communications between the two over the ethernet?